# How to load or populate the table from database values using Ajax?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

when I select a value from a drop down, It should change the table as per the value in the drop down using AJAX. I don't know how to do it.Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Here is the backend of dropdownlist and table;

```
public ActionResult Representatives()
    {
        ViewBag.reps = db.tbl_Users.Where(x=>x.fk_Roleid==2).ToList();
        var reps = db.tbl_CordinatorPayments.Include(t => t.tbl_Users).Where(x => x.fk_repId != null);
        return View(reps.ToList());
    }
```

Here is the dropdown list;

```
<select name="selectCity" id="CityDDL" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; height: 100%;" onchange="getValue()">
                <option value="-1">--Select Rep--</option>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.reps)
                {
                    <option value="@item.id">@item.Name</option>
                }

            </select>
```

and here is the table;

```
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="text-align: center;">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>#
                </th>
                <th>Rep Name
                </th>
                <th>Member Name
                </th>
                <th>Ubl %
                </th>
                <th>Shirts %
                </th>
                <th>Membership %
                </th>
                <th>Total
                </th>
                <th>Date
                </th>


            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tbl_Users.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tbl_Member.Member_Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PercentageUblAMount)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PercentageShirtsAmount)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PercentageMembershipAmount)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Total)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and this is how im getting the value of the drop down;

```
function getValue() {
    var value = $("#CityDDL").val();}
```

and then I want to this value to be used in an sql query like this;

```
select * from [tbl_CordinatorPayments] where fk_repId=id;
```

and then this query will populate the table which I dont know how to do.
Any help would be appreciated. THanks!!!

Comment: Where is your C# code?

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a controller that can handle the response that you would append to the table when the $.ajax() method is called

```
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET", //because you want to fetch data, not modify it
      url: //Your controller URl example: /Home/GetDataFromDropDown,
      data: {selectedDropdown: $("#dropdown1").val() } // here the id of the clicked dropdown select 
    })
      .done(function( result ) {
        //Here your data placeHolder + append the result of the call made to the controller 
        $("#newTable").append(result);
      });
```

---

```
//Create a controller that recives the kind of data you want, in this example "ActionResult"
public ActionResult GetDataFromDropDown(string selectedDropdown)
{
    var model = // do the SQL query or Linq query to populate the data with your logical needs
    return model;
}
```

---

I would recommend you use the strongtyped model binder for this controller and populate the new table with that model using Linq.
Go for a partial view for your table too, make it your "backbone code" and populate it when a valid model is called from the $.ajax()